# How to stop angular merging different pages to make them look the same?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, node.js

I have a chat website using node js and angular, and I have made the login/signup and chat page using these. but the problem is, whenever I load the chat page it uses the style from the other pages, and basically acts like a different section of the same page, It also merges the login/signup together, which is ok, because they have the same style just different number of form boxes, I want to stop angular from merging the styles from the login/signup with the chat and have it use its own style. 
All help would be very much apreciated, thanks in advance. 
And as far as I have been told and know, there is nothing in my own code that is preventing this, it is only angular itself. **strong text**By the way, As far as I know, certain things the body of the different pages cant be individually styled, and If I were to merge html's it would take a while and research and I dont really want to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of loading pages as partials is not loading its css and js files etc.

You need to have only one file as index.html and inside,

define `<ui-view>` tag this is where you have to load all your partials to, but not an entire page, having html tags and everything.

Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/3354046) pattern to load all your partials into one file. 
and then,

I highly recommend you check [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-ui-router-from-multiple-modules) web site out to set nodejs to set all the missing routes to your html file as well as defining your "/css", "/js" etc.

I have just merged these two working methods to make a very concrete restful application structure.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to avoid this problem is to write your css with starting parent class. In this way your css will work only if you have parent element with specific class.

```
.signIn .button {

}
.chat .button {
}
```

Write it like this and the button in different elements will have different style